# Get the rows which has same values one column

Tags: php, forms, csv, fgetcsv

I am getting data from a csv one basis of some index as follows:

```
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];      


     if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
     {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
        $rowCount = 0 ;
        $secondColumnArray = array();

        while (($getData = fgetcsv($file,  100000, ",")) !== FALSE)
         {
         if($rowCount >=0){

             if(strpos($getData[0],"Bestand")!==false){

             array_push($secondColumnArray, $getData[0]);

               }
             foreach ($secondColumnArray as $all_elements){

                $all_elements_refine = explode(',', $all_elements);

                $new_refine =  $all_elements_refine[0];

                $all_elements_refine1 = explode(';', $new_refine);

                $specialChars = array(" ", "\r", "\n", '"', "*");
                $replaceChars = array("", "", "");
                $all_elements_refine2 = str_replace($specialChars, $replaceChars, $all_elements_refine1);
                 print_r($all_elements_refine2);

             }

         }
                 ++$rowCount;

         }

        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($secondColumnArray);   echo "</pre>"; 
         fclose($file); 
     }
```

In the above example i am stat getting data from index 306 but that is not a good approach for me i only want to get those row which has value "Bestand" in first column.

For Example:

```
Row 1:  Bestand , 1 , Hell , World
Row 2:  farb    , 2 , Hell , World
Row 3:  Bestand , 3 , Hell , World
```

These Are the actual rows in my csv Check the fourth column in actual csv and after the filtering the csv i got the duplicate rows.

```
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842143;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842144;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842148;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842157;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842158;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842161;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842162;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling mondstein         ";"moonstone           ";000000000;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling mondstein         "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842346;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling grün              ";"green zirconia      ";000000047;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling grün              "            
Bestand   ;000000000;"I";00000000842349;000000000;00000095;009598;00000198;000000000;"MK Sterling grün              ";"green zirconia      ";000000047;000000000;000000800;"20160525";"*           ";000000100;000000000;000008990;000008990;000008990;1900;"MK Sterling grün              "
```

Duplicate of rows:

```
id  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W
1   Bestand 000000000   I   00000000842143  000000000   00000095    009598  00000198    000000000   MKSterlingmondstein moonstone   000000000   000000000   000000800   20160525        000000100   000000000   000008990   000008990   000008990   1900    MKSterlingmondstein
2   Bestand 000000000   I   00000000842143  000000000   00000095    009598  00000198    000000000   MKSterlingmondstein moonstone   000000000   000000000   000000800   20160525        000000100   000000000   000008990   000008990   000008990   1900    MKSterlingmondstein
3   Bestand 000000000   I   00000000842144  000000000   00000095    009598  00000198    000000000   MKSterlingmondstein moonstone   000000000   000000000   000000800   20160525        000000100   000000000   000008990   000008990   000008990   1900    MKSterlingmondstein
4   Bestand 000000000   I   00000000842143  000000000   00000095    009598  00000198    000000000   MKSterlingmondstein moonstone   000000000   000000000   000000800   20160525        000000100   000000000   000008990   000008990   000008990   1900    MKSterlingmondstein
5   Bestand 000000000   I   00000000842144  000000000   00000095    009598  00000198    000000000   MKSterlingmondstein moonstone   000000000   000000000   000000800   20160525        000000100   000000000   000008990   000008990   000008990   1900    MKSterlingmondstein
```

So I Just want the rows that has values "Bestand" in their first column How i can get that please help.

Comment: Do you mean: `if($all_elements[0]=="Bestand"){ // keep it}` ?  I'm not sure if you want to filter the rows after the `if` or inside the `foreach`.

Comment: Still Showing all the data..

Comment: please show me a few samples of `$getData[0]` and `$all_elements`.  Please edit this information directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite:

```
$filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
if($_FILES["file"]["size"]>0){
    $file=fopen($filename,"r");
    $rowCount=0;
    $secondColumnArray=[];
    while(($getData=fgetcsv($file,100000))!==false){
        if($rowCount>=306){
            if(strpos($getData[0],"Bestand")!==false){
                array_push($secondColumnArray, $getData[0]);
            }
            foreach($secondColumnArray as $all_elements){
                print_r($all_elements);
            }
        }
        ++$rowCount;
    }
    fclose($file); 
}
```

Comment: Here is the full code of my module on git:
https://github.com/shoaibgits/csv-by-row-to-database/

Comment: Duplication is the issue

Comment: I have insert this data from CSV to a table so it is duplicating the entries

Comment: @Shoaib Are you saying the csv file has duplicate rows and you want to filter them so that all rows are unique?  Like it is an additional step?

Comment: @Shaoib Please print to your screen a few $getData arrays and add them to your question then I will be able to refine your process and eliminate duplicates.  I also have some other suggestions for your GitHub files.

Comment: @Shoaib To deny duplicates, use `if(!in_array($getData,$secondColumnArray)){$secondColumnArray[]=$getData[0];}` (as a replacement for the `array_push` line), but I am still not convinced that your code is working as intended  or efficiently.  We may need to go to a chat room to iron this all out.  I don't want to leave a poor answer for other people to copy/paste.

Comment: @Shoaib because the first column in each row of the file is an `id` number (array element [0]) and the `Bestand` value is in the second column (array element[1]) I am worried that the `strpos` condition is looking in the wrong element for the `Bestand` string.  Let's work together to make this correct for all future readers.

Comment: @Shoaib Also, use `$replaceChars=''` to remove all special Chars.  `mysql_real_escape_string` should be updated as well.